# Localization of a model category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $M$ be a very nice model category (cofibrantly generated, combinatorial or cellular and left proper simplicial model category). Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$  and $g: X\rightarrow Z $ be two morphisms in $M$ such that $g$ is weak equivalence. Suppose that the map $r: Z\rightarrow Y\cup_{X} Z $ is a weak equivalence in the localized model category $\mathrm{L}_{\{ f\}}M$. Is it true that $\mathrm{L}_{\{ f\}}M=\mathrm{L}_{\{ r\}}M$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $M$ be the category of simplicial sets with the Kan model structure. Let $S^1$ be $\Delta^1$ with its endpoints identified and let $f : \Delta^1 \to S^1$ be the obvious map. Let $g : \Delta^1 \to \Delta^0$ be the unique map. Then $r : \Delta^0 \to \Delta^0$ is the identity map, so it is a weak equivalence even in $M$, so $L_{\{r\}}M = M$, but $L_{\{f\}}M \neq M$ since $S^1$ is not equivalent to $\Delta^1$ in $M$.